# Can I call any book a sequel of any other book based on my personal opinion?

Tags: nouns

If I personally think that book B would be a great read for those who have already ready book A, am I able to call book B "a great sequel" to book A?

For example, can I say the following?

> I love the book *Tortoises in the Caribbean* by John Murphy. A great sequel to that book is *The Ecology of Tortoises* by Christopher Sampson.

Is this legitimate use of the word "sequel", even though the two authors don't know of each other?

Comment: Do dictionaries appear to like this usage?

Comment: If the book is by the same author and deals with related themes, but is not technically in the same series, you can call it a *spiritual sequel*. But usually you must remain within the corpus of a single author (or the same fictional world).

Comment: If you're looking for an alternate term, "follow-up" might work.

Comment: A great next book to read is ...

Comment: If you can make the case that it functions as a sequel, you should be able to use sequel to describe it, especially in the sentence as you've constructed it. You've named the two authors, so there shouldn't be any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[From Merriam-Wesbter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequel)

sequel: a book, movie, etc., that continues a story begun in another book, movie, etc

It doesn't necessarily have to be from the same author/director/whatever (consider the Star Trek movies), but it does need to have some direct connection to the prequel, to be in the same "universe." *Lonesome Dove* takes place chronologically after *Gone with the Wind*, but it's not a sequel.

Comment: On the other hand, the novel *[Scarlett](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlett_(Ripley_novel))* can be called a sequel to *Gone with the Wind* even though it has no official connection with the *GWTW's* author or publisher.

Comment: @AlanCarmack True, and that's why I said "It doesn't necessarily have to be from the same author/director/whatever". Scarlett "begins where Gone with the Wind left off" and was intended to be a sequel. ((I'm not sure if you're disagreeing with me or just pointing out another example.))

Comment: Just giving another example! In contrast to *Lonesome Dove*.

Comment: Ah, gotcha!     ......

Answer (score 0):

No.

A sequel has to be deliberately crafted as a continuance of another work. If they just happen to go well together, that that does not make it a sequel.

A better term here would be "follow-up."

Having said that, there is sometimes a gray area. People sometimes speculate that two works were intentionally related even if it has never been officially confirmed. For example, some people believe that "How I Met Your Mother" was intentionally written to resemble a prequel to "Full House," even though they are not officially related.